# JQM: programmably change the label for an input

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a text input with a label:

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="number">Amount:</label>
<input type="number" name="number" id="vitalamount" value=""  />
</li>
```

I'm now trying to change the label of the input, but the following code didn't work.

```
$("#vitalamount").attr("label","something else");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr` modifies the attributes of an element not it's sibling elements, you can use `prev()` or `siblings` for selecting the `label` and changing it's texts:

```
$("#vitalamount").siblings("label").text('something else');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include the form field inside the label tag, then you should use the for attribute to associate it with the id of the form element you want to label.

[Reference](http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/aa052206.htm/)

So, put `id` in `for` attribute not `name`.

Amount:

Now, if you the `id` of input as `vitalamount`

```
$('label[for="vitalamount"]').html('New value of label');
```